# Linear regression models in R - available options and corresponding equations

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to get into linear models with R and I try to find the available options for the `lm()` function. For instance, I can use `lm(y~x)` meaning the equation between `y` and `x` is `y=a*x+e`. Additionally the term `I(x^2)` can be used for quadratic. Is there any available full list of the relations that can be computed in R with their equations?

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-formula-tutorial) might be helpful. Another way of specifying a quadratic function is `y ~ poly(x, 2)`, which will include both the linear and quadratic terms. Also, `y ~ x` is fitting the equation `y = a + b*x + e`, where `a` and `b` are the regression coefficients (`a` is the intercept and `b` is the slope).

Comment: @eipi10 thank you very much. It is pretty much what I have been looking for. Any other sources are welcome :)

Comment: The book *Modern Applied Statistics with S-Plus* is good for this.